# Creating Setups in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, clickonce, installation

I have read some blogs which say we cannot create MSI files from VS 2012.

I have a below requirement could you please suggest me the recommendation.

I should create a setup which will install following,
1) WPF Application.
2) Windows Service.
3) A 3rd Party Application.

Thanks and Regards,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 2):

I use Wix 3.6 in Visual Studio 2012 and am fully able to create an MSI.

I would recommend using Wix as it is very powerful and can easily do all you need to do.